# Background colouring (highlighting) for maths formula in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, highlighting

I want to highlight selected maths formulas in Lyx.

Is there a simple  way of doing this from the GUI ?

I have tried selecting and right-clicking -> Text style , but that seems to change the font colour, not the background colour :

[image]

I have also tried the box menu -> shaded highlight, but the highlighting runs all the way across the page for some reason (in the PDF as well as in the Lyx GUI):

[image]

I am able to do this by entering Latex code for the highlighting and the formula, but I was hoping this highlighting from the Lyx GUI.

I am using Lyx version 2.2.3 with TexLive.

Comment: It runs across the whole page because that is the default configuration of a *Shaded background* box. You can change the width in the settings. Unrelated: when writing `ln` and `exp`, use `\ln` and `\exp`, then they are properly typeset.

Comment: Currently, 'Settings..' says 'minipage'. Do i need to change that to 'parbox' or 'none' ? Also, yes there is a width setting, but do i need to type in (guess) a value ?

Comment: No need to change type. As far as I can see, you have set the width manually, yes. At least with that method, I don't know if LyX has any other options built-in. By the way, you said you could do it by writing code. Exactly how did you do it?

Comment: I normally use TexStudio rather than Lyx, and I use this:

{code}
%%highlight with \hl
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\colorlet{highlightgreen}{green!10}
\colorlet{highlightgray}{gray!20}
\sethlcolor{highlightgreen}
{code}

then i can use  \hl{} with the formula inside

Comment: You could use the old trick of writing `\hl{` in an ERT, then write the inline math using LyX's GUI, and finally another ERT with `}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick hack for using `\hl`, is to write only `\hl{` and `}` in ERTs, and write the math stuff using the LyX GUI. So it might look like this:

[image]

Another option is to define a new custom inset for `\hl`. Go to Document --> Settings --> Local layout, and add this:

```
InsetLayout Flex:highlight
    LyxType               custom
    LabelString           hl
    LatexType             command
    LatexName             hl
    Font
      Series              Bold
    EndFont
    Preamble
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \colorlet{highlightgreen}{green!10}
    \colorlet{highlightgray}{gray!20}
    \sethlcolor{highlightgreen} 
    EndPreamble
    InToc                 false
    HTMLTag               strong
    ResetsFont true
End
```

(Alternatively skip the Preamble block, and add those to the preamble manually.)

Now you should find *hightlight* under Insert -> Custom insets:

[image]

Add one of those insets, and add the inline math inside it. Might look like this:

[image]